# how to format contract params expecting bytes32?

Tags: web3js, transactions, bytes32

I have a contract that expects a bytes32 parameter called "topic" which I pass in like this:

```
web3.utils.hexToBytes(web3.utils.stringToHex("Weather"));
```

I also tried

```
web3.utils.stringToHex("Weather")
```

and just passing it in as "Weather" and that didn't work.

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: invalid bytes32 value (arg="_topic", coderType="bytes32", value=[87,101,97,116,104,101,114], version=4.0.27)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work out you have to change string type to byte32

```
web3.padRight(web3.fromAscii('hello'), 34)
"0x68656c6c6f0000000000000000000000"
```